# Service account cannot view show calendars explicitly shared with it

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I am trying to access all organisation calendars from a Service Account but calendars/events are not viewable - even though they have been **explicitly** shared with the Service Account.

I have followed the [delegation instructions](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation). and the [Drive example for instantiating a service](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#instantiate_a_drive_service_object) (converted to the Calendar service).

I was surprised that the Service Account cannot automatically have Administrator-level access to calendars but even explicit sharing is not delivering the access needed.

If anyone spots something I have missed or misunderstood, then please let me know. Any help would be appreciated.

Mike

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'google-api-php-    client-master/src');
require_once 'google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php'; // or wherever autoload.php is located

require_once "google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php";
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Calendar.php";
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Oauth2.php";

define('CALENDAR_SCOPE', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly');
define('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL', 'DEV_EMAIL@developer.gserviceaccount.com');
define('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH', 'P12_FILE.p12');

function buildService($userEmail) {
  $key = file_get_contents(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
  $auth = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
      array(CALENDAR_SCOPE),
      $key);
  $auth->sub = $userEmail;
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
  return new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
}

$v_calendarId_primary = "USER_CHOSEN@email.com";

$service = buildService($v_calendarId_primary);

$calendarId = 'primary';
$optParams = array(
  'maxResults' => 10,
  'orderBy' => 'startTime',
  'singleEvents' => TRUE,
  'timeMin' => date('c'),
);

$results = $service->events->listEvents($v_calendarId_primary, $optParams);

if (count($results->getItems()) == 0) {
  print "No upcoming events found.\n<br>";
} else {
  print "Upcoming events:\n<br>";
  foreach ($results->getItems() as $event) {
    $start = $event->start->dateTime;
    if (empty($start)) {
      $start = $event->start->date;
    }
    printf("%s (%s)\n <br>", $event->getSummary(), $start);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and do a [calendar.get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get) on USER_CHOSEN@email.com.  This will ensure that you have access to the calendar it self.  Then double check what permissions you gave the service account.  At the very least you are going to need see all event details.

[image]

your code looks fine to me I just don't think you have access.

Comment: Thanks for checking that DalmTo much appreciated.  I have more information on this now which might help. If I run my app in **incognito mode** then it of course does not have to log in due to the service account credentials. However, the **user** needs to log in to access the environment the app is running on and I now realise it is _their_ credentials / permissions that are being asserted  here - rather than the service account.  So, I need to somehow ignore the logged in user's credentials.

Comment: To further complicate the issue, the end goal is to **embed** the target calendar but such attempts throw an X-Frame deny as it tries to display a login box in the incognito window, So, I can list the events but now embed - odd.